# Please simplify wand operations?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I'm looking to understand wand activation?

What I believe:

1. Using the wand will activate it.
2. Wands are spell trigger items.
3. Use Magic Device (UMD) works on spell-trigger items.

My understanding is this is how it works in the game.

I first need to roll a UMD DC 20 activate the wand of Scorching Ray.

Do I still need to make a ranged touch attack roll on target or is the UMD check to activate the wand also the RTA roll itself.

Or is the UMD check the activation and the RTA roll the spell-trigger?

Comment: You might get better answers (and perhaps better voting) if you include *why* you thought things might work the way you describe: they don’t, and as far as I can tell anyway, there is no indication anywhere that they do, so this question is just kind of confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you must roll UMD (assuming you have no levels in classes that have *scorching ray* on their spell lists) to activate the wand and cast the spell, and then you must do everything the spell says—including roll one or more ranged attack rolls to actually hit with your rays.

Substituting one roll for another is a very rare thing, and will always be called out explicitly. Substituting a skill check for an attack roll or saving throw is rarer still, since skill checks are **much** easier to make. It would not be at all fair to use your UMD check against a target’s touch AC.

Usually, characters try to ensure their UMD is high enough to guarantee a check of 20 (normally requiring a +19 bonus), and/or try to stick to wands that are not time-sensitive. Combat spells are generally very poor in magic items, because you have to pay extravagantly for caster level and the save DC is so poor. If you find a *wand of scorching ray*, you are much better off selling it than using it.

Answer (score 4):

The Use Magic Device check **only** activates the spell trigger item. It has no influence over the spell effect. Once the item activates, its spell effect proceeds as normal using the item's caster level.

So using a *wand of scorching ray* has the following steps. Activating a wand is a standard action that does not provoke an attack of opportunity.

1. Activate the wand as a standard action by succeeding on a DC 20 Use Magic Device check. If successful, proceed to step 2. If failure, nothing happens and no charges are wasted, but you still lose the standard action. If your class has *scorching ray* on its spell list, then you do not need to attempt a UMD check.
2. The wand casts *scorching ray* using the wand's caster level (usually 3 for a 2nd level spell). The spell goes into effect, and a charge from the wand is consumed.
3. Because the spell fires a ray, you must succeed on a ranged touch attack.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Once again: **do not use comments to ask new questions**.